# Generating line breaks for Excel HTML based documents on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, export-to-excel

I am successfully generating Excel documents using the HTML method by simply generating an HTML table, setting the mimetype to application/msexcel, and ensuring the filename generated has a .xls extension.  This method works extremely well for both Windows and Mac version of Excel.

However, I have a requirement to generate line breaks within a cell.

If I use `<br/>` within a `<td>` then Excel actually splits the content into a new cell for each line break.  There is an easy work around for this problem by either embedding a style in the br tag as follows `<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;">` which tells Excel to keep the line break within the cell, or by defining the style `br { mso-data-placement:same-cell; }` in the header of the HTML document.

The problem I have is that this style does not work correctly for Mac OS X Excel.  When Excel sees the mso-data-placement style it correctly keeps the content within the same cell, however it incorrectly ignores the br altogether so all line breaks are ignored.

Does anyone know how to create a line break within a cell within an HTML Excel file for Mac OS X?

Thanks
Matt